Problem with sendgrid on azure vm/No emails sent on VM
I have created a vm in Azure Microsoft and I want to send email notifications. The problem is that even though if I run my spring boot application locally it sends the email but if I try it from the vm it does not send anything. I have tried both restricted and full access API keys from Sendgrid's website. This is for example an error that pops when I send the request:
401
{"errors":[{"message":"The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, or revoked","field"
,"help"
}]}

{Strict-Transport-Security=max-age=600; includeSubDomains, Server=nginx, Access-Control-Allow-Origin=https://sendgrid.api-docs.io, Access-Control-Allow-Methods=POST, Connection=keep-alive, X-No-CORS-Reason=https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html, Content-Length=116, Access-Control-Max-Age=600, Date=Wed, 19 Jun 2024 17:54:06 GMT, Access-Control-Allow-Headers=Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl, Content-Type=application/json}

This is the application properties file(on the comments there are some attempts i have tried and did not work):
server.port=9090

spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=pass123
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/aimodosia

# auto generate sql and update db schema at startup
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

#show and format sql
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

#dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect


# App Properties
app.jwtSecret=123esef
app.jwtExpirationMs=99900000

#TRY OLD MAIL
sendgrid.key=abcd

#app.sendgrid.key=abc

### Mail Properties
#spring.mail.host=smtp.sendgrid.net
#spring.mail.port=587
#spring.mail.username=new-try
#spring.mail.password=${app.sendgrid.key}
#spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
#spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
#spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true

management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled=true
management.health.livenessState.enabled=true
management.health.readinessState.enabled=true

This is the config file
@Configuration
public class Sendgridconfig {

    @Value("${sendgrid.key}")
    private String appKey;

    @Bean
    public SendGrid sendGrid(){
        return new SendGrid(appKey);
    }
}

This is the service
@Service
public class EmailService {

    @Autowired
    SendGrid sendGrid;

    public void sendEmail(String to, String subject, String body) throws IOException {
        Email from = new Email("it2021077@hua.gr");
        Email toEmail = new Email(to);
        Content content = new Content("text/plain", body);
        Mail mail = new Mail(from, subject, toEmail, content);

        Request request = new Request();
        try {
            request.setMethod(Method.POST);
            request.setEndpoint("mail/send");
            request.setBody(mail.build());
            Response response = sendGrid.api(request);
            System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
            System.out.println(response.getBody());
            System.out.println(response.getHeaders());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}


and this is an example of how I use it in a rest controller
 @PostMapping("/{user_id}/new")
    @Secured("ROLE_SECRETARY")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> saveDonationRequest(@PathVariable Integer user_id, @RequestBody DonationRequest donationRequest) {
        Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<>();

        if (donationRequestRepository.findByLocationAndDate(donationRequest.getLocation(), donationRequest.getDate()).isPresent()) {
            System.out.println("Donation Request already exists.");
            response.put("error", "Error. Donation Request already exists.");
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(response);
        } else if (donationRequest.getDate() == null || donationRequest.getLocation().isBlank() || donationRequest.getDate().isBefore(LocalDate.now())) {
            response.put("error", "Invalid donation request details.");
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(response);
        } else {
            User user = userDetailsService.getUser(user_id);
            String email = user.getEmail();
            Secretary secretary = secretaryRepository.findByEmail(email).orElse(null);
            if (secretary != null) {
                System.out.println("GDGDHFGDFG");
                donationRequest.setSecretary(secretary);
                donationRequestService.saveDonationRequest(donationRequest);

                // Send confirmation email
                try {
                    String subject = "New Donation Request Submitted";
                    String body = "A new donation request has been created for " + donationRequest.getLocation() + " on " + donationRequest.getDate() + ".";
                    emailservice.sendEmail(email, subject, body);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    response.put("error", "Your request has been done, but mail failed to send");
                    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(response);
                }

                response.put("success", "Created New Donation Request and sent confirmation email.");
                return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
            } else {
                response.put("error", "Secretary not found.");
                return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(response);
            }
        }
    }

